Оформление неполных имён собственных
Допустим, существует организация "Объединение Людей". Для удобства организацию называют "объединением". Как это оформляется на письме? Нужно ли писать с заглавной буквы? Нужны ли кавычки?

В "Объединении" ситуация неспокойная... думаю, оно скоро развалится.


✦ Я считаю, что при сокращении названия, заключенного в кавычки, надо оставить и прописную букву, и кавычки.
В "Объединении" ситуация неспокойная... Думаю, оно скоро развалится.
• Из справочника издателя и автора (А. Э. Мильчин, Л. К. Чельцова; стр. 65):

3.14.2. Неполное название, заменяющее полное
С прописной буквы пишется первое (или единственное) слово усеченного названия. Напр.: Государственный литературный музей — Литературный музей, Центральный дом художника — Дом художника...

• Пример ("Крылья Советов" ➜ "Крылья"):
«Крылья» проиграли в дебютном матче Кубка России махачкалинскому «Динамо» (АиФ).

Интересно в этом справочнике пишут, рекомендуем так-то, однако ни одного примера с единственным словом усечённого названия не дадим... Допустим, есть название "Золотой век", при усечении оно будет "век" или "Век"? Если второе, то по такой логике во всех названиях каждое слово должно быть с прописной буквы, иначе теряется последовательность, но такого в русском языке не наблюдается.
